# SPARQL Query to get a company by name if it contains text

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to get a company by name if it contains text

Example:  honda motor co ltd

Maps to: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q9584

I have this query that finds apple successfully

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
select distinct ?iri ?logo ?description {
  ?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
       dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description ;
       rdfs:label ?lbl ;
       foaf:depiction|dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?logo .
   ?lbl bif:contains "'apple'"@en  .
  filter( langMatches(lang(?description),"en") )
}
```

Which returns results since it matches 'Apple Inc'
http://dbpedia.org/page/Apple_Inc.

But this query below doesn't match Accenture

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
select distinct ?iri ?logo ?description {
  ?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
       dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description ;
       rdfs:label ?lbl ;
       foaf:depiction|dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?logo .
   ?lbl bif:contains "'accenture'"@en  .
  filter( langMatches(lang(?description),"en") )
}
```

I expect: http://dbpedia.org/page/Accenture
but get nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every resource in RDF must have every property! In your case, the logo doesn't exist which means you should make it an optional feature:

```sql
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        

SELECT DISTINCT ?iri ?logo ?description {
  ?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
       dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description ;
       rdfs:label ?lbl .
  ?lbl bif:contains "'accenture'"@en  .
  FILTER( langMatches(lang(?description),"en") )
  OPTIONAL {?iri foaf:depiction|dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?logo }
}
```